# How to use pounds as currency when buying Ubuntu One storage?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am trying to buy more storage to my Ubuntu One account. I live in UK and the purchase form detects that. However, the form allows me to choose between euros and dollars. Why is pounds not in the list? How can I make my purchase in pounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found this bug report -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/682925 -- it's marked as *In Progress* so maybe pounds will be supported soon.